# How to enlarge a div without moving other elements

Tags: css, html, scale

How can I stop this div to move all elements below where you select certain price?

To see what I am talking about please look at this link: [Check the price table style 3](http://www.dreamtemplate.com/dreamcodes/documentation/pricingtables.html)
below that you can see that when you select certain price table all of the elements below are moving because of the pop-out. I want to be able to use this feature but of course without moving all of the elements below.

How can I do that?

Here is the link to a Javascript:[JS](http://www.dreamtemplate.com/dreamcodes/pricingtables/js/tsc_pricingtables.js)

EDIT:

I am posting relevant HTML:

```
<!-- DC Pricing Tables:3 Start -->
  <div class="tsc_pricingtable03 tsc_pt3_style1">
    <div class="caption_column">
      <ul>
        <li class="header_row_1 align_center radius5_topleft"></li>
        <li class="header_row_2">
          <h2 class="caption">Choose plan</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="row_style_4"><span>Web Space</span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2"><span>Bandwidth</span></li>
        <li class="row_style_4"><span>E-mail accounts</span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2"><span>MySQL databases</span></li>
        <li class="row_style_4"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Web-based control panel system">CPANEL</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="24/7 Support via Phone, Email, Web.">24/7 Support</a></span></li>
        <li class="footer_row"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column_1">
      <ul>
        <li class="header_row_1 align_center">
          <h2 class="col1">starter</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="header_row_2 align_center">
          <h1 class="col1">$<span>5</span></h1>
          <h3 class="col1">per month</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="row_style_3 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">10GB</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_1 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">100GB</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_3 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Tooltip info.">1</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_1 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">1</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_3 align_center"><span class="pricing_no"></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_1 align_center"><span class="pricing_yes"></span></li>
        <li class="footer_row"><a href="" class="tsc_buttons2 grey">sign up!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column_2">
      <ul>
        <li class="header_row_1 align_center">
          <h2 class="col2">basic</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="header_row_2 align_center">
          <h1 class="col2">$<span>10</span></h1>
          <h3 class="col2">per month</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="row_style_4 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">30GB</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">200GB</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_4 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Tooltip info.">10</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">10</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_4 align_center"><span class="pricing_yes"></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2 align_center"><span class="pricing_yes"></span></li>
        <li class="footer_row"><a href="" class="tsc_buttons2 grey">sign up!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column_3">
      <ul>
        <li class="header_row_1 align_center">
          <h2 class="col3">pro</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="header_row_2 align_center">
          <h1 class="col3">$<span>29</span></h1>
          <h3 class="col3">per month</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="row_style_3 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">100GB</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_1 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">500GB</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_3 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Tooltip info.">50</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_1 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">50</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_3 align_center"><span class="pricing_yes"></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_1 align_center"><span class="pricing_yes"></span></li>
        <li class="footer_row"><a href="" class="tsc_buttons2 grey">sign up!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column_4">
      <ul>
        <li class="header_row_1 align_center radius5_topright">
          <h2 class="col4">biz</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="header_row_2 align_center">
          <h1 class="col4">$<span>39</span></h1>
          <h3 class="col4">per month</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="row_style_4 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">Unlimited</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">1000GB</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_4 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Tooltip info.">Unlimited</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2 align_center"><span><a href="#" class="tooltip" rel="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">Unlimited</a></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_4 align_center"><span class="pricing_yes"></span></li>
        <li class="row_style_2 align_center"><span class="pricing_yes"></span></li>
        <li class="footer_row"><a href="" class="tsc_buttons2 grey">sign up!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- DC Pricing Tables:3 End -->
<div class="tsc_clear"></div> <!-- line break/clear line -->
```

And the CSS:

```
div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_1,
div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_2,
div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_3,
div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_4 { /* transitions */ -webkit-transition:box-shadow 0.1s ease; -moz-transition:box-shadow 0.1s ease; -o-transition:box-shadow 0.1s ease; -ms-transition:box-shadow 0.1s ease; transition:box-shadow 0.1s ease;}
div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_1:hover,
div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_2:hover,
div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_3:hover,
div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_4:hover { position:relative; z-index:100; left:-5px; top:-15px; /* shadow */ box-shadow:5px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); -webkit-box-shadow:5px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); -moz-box-shadow:5px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```

Comment: Confusingly worded question. What I believe he is asking is - When you hover over a column in the third table down - it 'pops out.' This popout effect causes the elements below the table to shift down. He would like to prevent the shifting.

Comment: Please post the relevant html and js (not linked) in your question, as well as how they work in conjunction. SO question are supposed to avoid the 'this is broken - please go look at it and fix it for me' genre.

Comment: @mrtsherman I just need to know what is making such behavior? As I really can't see it. All of the code is in the web page...html, JS

Comment: A major point of SO is to provide a repository of knowledge that others can utilize. By placing your code on an external site, liable to change or 404, you make your question useless to those in the future.

Comment: You will be able to fix this if you set magine for the `div` (which is moving)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the corrected css rule below.

```css
  div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_1:hover, 
  div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_2:hover, 
  div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_3:hover, 
  div.tsc_pricingtable03 div.column_4:hover {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 100;
      left: -5px;
      top: -15px;
      box-shadow: 5px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      margin-bottom: -30px; /// Note the added removal of the bottom margin that all "non" active elements have
  }
```

This is needed because you are giving the wrapper a 100% height so it will ALWAYS maintain that 24px padding.  However, to keep the `:hover` element from changing the height of the wrapper you need to have that element specifically remove all the padding added by the wrapper to effectively ignore it.

Comment: On a side note as mentioned in the question comments.  You should really post the relevant markup for that html and the non `:hover` and the `:hover` css.  You can simply copy and paste and hit the code format button and this will make sure that the needed code (as is relevant to this question) is always preserved...regardless of the changes you need to make on your site.

Comment: Better than my initial thought (to set the height to height+30 of container div), +1

Answer (score 9):

You can also consider using the CSS `transform` property, a technique that is also used in your fourth table. For example:

```css
.some_table .some-table-column:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

CSS transforms are ideal for this, as they ["allow to change the position of the affected content without disrupting the normal flow"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transforms).