# How do I use CSS transitions to fixed position a scaled element?

Tags: css

This seems like a lack of understanding on my part. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417433/how-to-enlarge-a-div-without-moving-other-elements) offers some insight but not exactly waht I'm trying to do.

I have a DIV which I want to shrink and reposition like a minimize effect. I am able to use scale to do this but it retains the original size for positioning (as expected) I want to detach the element instead.

```
.scales.tiny {
  transform: scale(0.3);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

I have a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/poqatu/2/edit) that illistrates this.

How do I reposition / clip a scaled element in CSS?

Comment: What do you mean by detach? Your question is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform-origin` to lock the trasformation on the right and then add a translate to move it down:

http://jsbin.com/hilekawa/1/

```
.scales {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.scales.tiny {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3) translateY(500px);
}
```