# How can I stop my other DIVs from moving when I expand on hover

Tags: html, css

My other DIVs keep moving when one of my DIVs expand on hover

```css
#entertainment
{
 width:49%;
 height: 49%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; 
 grid-gap: 10%;
 border: 1px solid red;
 float: left;
}

#circle
{
 position: relative;
 overflow: auto;
  width: 80%;
 padding-top: 80%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 transform:translate(-5%, 0);
transition: all 0.5s ease;

align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

#circle:hover
{
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 100%;

}
```

```html
    <body>
    
    <div id="entertainment">
    <div id="circle" style="background-image: url('Instagram.jpg'); transform:translate(5%, 0);" ></div>
    <div id="circle" style="background-image: url('Logo.jpg'); " ></div>
    <div id="circle" style="background-image: url('Netflix.jpg'); transform:translate(-10%, 0);" ></div>
    <div id="circle" style="background-image: url('spotify.jpg'); transform:translate(5%, 0);" ></div>
    <div id="circle" style="background-image: url('Amazon.jpg'); " ></div>
    <div id="circle" style="background-image: url('Snapchat.jpg'); transform:translate(-10%, 0);" ></div>
    
    </div>
    </body>
```

The other Divs keep moving when I hover over one and there is no padding pushing them. It seems like there is an object pushing the other divs as I expand and I am very confused as to what is doing it.
Please help as I need to finish this, thanks

Comment: When you make the div bigger, it is well.. bigger, it takes up more space and pushes everything else out of the way. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417433/how-to-enlarge-a-div-without-moving-other-elements) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the `width` on :hover, change the size with `transform: scale(1.25)`. The value in the `scale()` function can be whatever you want (1 equals 100% or full size).

When changing the size using transform, the other elements should maintain their position in the layout.